# How to create new permission for custom post types for doing specific tasks

Tags: custom-post-types, permissions, user-access

I am in the need to create new permissions with the following access:

Post_Type_A (Custom post type): Access to Post_Type_A content type
Post_Type_B (Custom post type): Access to Post_Type_B content type

I am new to WordPress and no idea where to start. If someone please guide me about this I would be grateful.

Regards

Comment: So you need to give some users the access to Post_Type_A and some users to Post_Type_B , and other user can't access them, right ? So my question is are those ***CPT***'s created by you ? Or created by some other code, you just need to create the permissions ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. "some users the access to Post_Type_A and some users to Post_Type_B , and other user can't access them" - yes.  CPT's are already created. I only need to create the permissions. I don't have the ability to install any plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code-

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'the_dramatist_add_role_caps', 999 );
function the_dramatist_add_role_caps() {
    // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types
    $roles = array( 'editor', 'administrator' );

    // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
    foreach($roles as $the_role) {

        $role = get_role($the_role);

        $role->add_cap( 'read' );
        $role->add_cap( 'read_{Post_Type_A_Name}' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'read_private_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_{Post_Type_A_Name}' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'publish_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_{Post_Type_A_Name}s' ); // Also do for Post_Type_B

    }
}
```

This way you can add permission to any user roles.

If you wanna create a new role for the user who should get permission then create a new role like below-

```
function add_the_dramatist_role() {
    add_role('the_dramatist_role',
             'The Dramatist Role',
             array(
                 'read' => true,
                 'edit_posts' => false,
                 'delete_posts' => false,
                 'publish_posts' => false,
                 'upload_files' => true,
             )
    );
}
// Remember this must be called plugin main file.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'add_the_dramatist_role' );
```

Then add `the_dramatist_role` to the previous function `the_dramatist_add_role_caps`'s `$roles` variable like this-

```
$roles = array( 'the_dramatist_role', 'editor', 'administrator' );
```

Now `the_dramatist_role` will have all those privileges.

Hope the above helps.